# Error on Loadup After Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: startup, acpi

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18 to 20.04.1 LTS, and while there haven't been too many issues, sometimes when I boot up my computer I get this message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sGhP.jpg

```
[0.425594] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000b042dc68 (20190816/exresop=66)
[0.425661] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store} (20190816/dswexec=431)
[0.425746] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_.PR.CPUO._PDC due to previous error (AE_AML_Operand_Type) (20190816/psperse=529)
```

Is there a particular way to fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu has both releases with the format *yy.mm* (eg. 20.04) and *yy* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20). Please clarify your release, there is no Ubuntu 20, do you mean Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or Ubuntu Core 20, as releases using format *yy* are different products to *yy.mm* releases.

Comment: Has your computer recently received a firmware or BIOS update? If so, check the BIOS settings to ensure the boot mode is still set to “ACPI”. If it’s in “Legacy” mode, the system will not boot.

Comment: I haven't done a firmware or BIOS update, unfortunately.